# Can Admob and Adsense Ads Be Used Together in Same Android App?

Tags: java, android, admob, adsense, policy

Please read my question by examining the picture. I drew a simple image for clarity

Illustration =>(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzOSH.jpg)

I have a website and I want to use Adsense ads..
I have Admob account and mobile app in the same Google account.

This mobile application has Admob banner and interstitial ads.

I want to show my Adsense ads website as WebView in my application.

Will there be a problem according to Adsense policies?

I have read the Adsense and Admob policies

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.